# read the HTTP header to check for 404 with jQuery without performing an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, google-analytics, http-status-code-404

Is there a way to read the HTTP header with jQuery *without* performing a `.ajax` request and reading `xhr.status`?

Along similar lines to the popular Google Analytics addon ([gaAddons](http://jsfiddle.net/shamel67/VzbPw/1/)) I wish to track 404s on my site. Unfortunately, I have inherited a legacy system and 404s do not have a unique URL.

Is it possible to read the HTTP header using jQuery?

Comment: Do you want to know whether the *current* page is a 404 page? Or are you trying to find out if a different URL returns a 404 page without actually making a request to that URL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible - they are not exposed to JavaScript. An AJAX request is the obvious workaround - not sure why you're against this.

More info in this question: [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the 404 error page, you could inject javascript into the 404 page that can send page details like, url, time etc to server through ajax [but it's point less if they *are* in server logs]. But then, this script can be exploited.

Comment: If I go to `www.ayrshiremins.com/abcdefg` this page doesn't exist, so I will be redirected (in My PHP) to `www.ayrshireminis.com/error`. This error page is used for other purposes other than 404s so how would you suggest I track the 404?

Comment: If you could see if abcdefg is a valid page, then when you are redirected to error, check if referrer is a valid page. if it's not, log the referrer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this in jQuery:

```
if ( $('meta[content="Not Found - The URL you requested could not be found."]').length>0 ) {
    /* do something about it */
}
```

This assumes that the delivery engine has put the following meta tag in the header of the page. Tumblr does this, for example.  Your own system may put a different meta tag or you could design your system to deliver some such meta tag.

```
<meta name="description" content="Not Found - The URL you requested could not be found." />
```

Of course, all this is really doing is checking the meta header which offers a page summary. But you could take advantage of the mechanism in your own environment.

Answer (score 0):

While doing site analytics i had to record errors separately.

Similar to @Octopus suggestion i added a meta tag to 404 and 500 pages.

```
<meta name="error" content="404">
```

On the client i then checked if this meta tag existed like so:

```
<script>
  meta = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

  for (i=0; i< meta.length; i++) {

    if(meta[i].name == 'error'){
       alert('This page returned a ' + meta[i].content + ' error');   
    }

  }

</script>
```

Unfortunately i had to use vanilla JS to achieve this.